# add new array entry to a function inside method in another class

Tags: php, oop

Not sure if my question is correct but what im trying to achive is to add cc to wp_mail that is inside a method of another class.

```
class Hello_World {

  function __construct () {
    ....
  }

  function dispatch_email() {
    $to = 'To: email@email.com';
    $subject = 'Subject';
    $body = 'Content';
    $header[] = 'From: from@email.com';
    $header[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $header );
  }

}
```

how can i add new header[] in wp_mail from my new class? i tried below but not working..

```
$Hi_World = new Hello_World;
$Hi_World->dispatch_email()->header[] = 'Cc: new@email.com';
```

Comment: You didn't return '`wp_mail` in your function ?

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on my phone, so I can't test but, if you add a parameter to your constructor, you can achieve your goals with something like this:

```php
class Hello_World {

  function __construct ($headers) {
    this->headers = $headers;
    ....
  }

  function dispatch_email() {
    $to = 'To: email@email.com';
    $subject = 'Subject';
    $body = 'Content';
    $header[] = 'From: from@email.com';
    $header[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
    $fullHeaders = array_merge($header, this->headers);

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $fullHeaders );
  }
}

$Hi_World = new Hello_World(['Cc: new@email.com']);
$Hi_World->dispatch_email();
```